docker and pgcli errors
So, Im currently trying to get into data engineering and was playing around with docker and pgcli and was hit.
sirik@Lenovo_Ideapad MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/DockerSQL
$ winpty docker run -it  \
     -e POSTGRES_USER="root"  \
     -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD="root" \ 
     -e POSTGRES_DB="ny_taxi"  \
     -v //c/Users/sirik/OneDrive/Desktop/DockerSQL/ny_taxi_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/   
     -p 5432:5431  \ 
     postgres:13

 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; 
 Skipping initialization

2024-08-14 11:27:17.982 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.16 (Debian 13.16-1.
pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64
-bit
2024-08-14 11:27:17.983 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port
5432
2024-08-14 11:27:17.983 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-08-14 11:27:17.988 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgre
sql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-08-14 11:27:18.036 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-
14 10:13:18 UTC
2024-08-14 11:27:18.096 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connect
ions

This part looks alright to me
sirik@Lenovo_Ideapad MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/DockerSQL
$ winpty pgcli -h localhost -p 5432 -u root -d ny_taxi

tried the above command and was hit with the connection failed error despite entering root as the password. The same had worked well the previous night but today it just refuses to work.
The logs look alright as well.
sirik@Lenovo_Ideapad MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/DockerSQL
$ docker logs funny_matsumoto

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2024-08-14 11:27:17.982 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.16 (Debian 13.16-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-08-14 11:27:17.983 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-08-14 11:27:17.983 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-08-14 11:27:17.988 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-08-14 11:27:18.036 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-14 10:13:18 UTC
2024-08-14 11:27:18.096 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

Im also able to manually connect to the database inside the container
and play around with tables.
It worked alright last night and was able to play around with tables but it just refuses to work today.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to replace all of the image links with plain text?  Make sure your question includes a [mcve]: the exact error message, the application code that produces the error, and any required Docker-related setup need to be directly in the question as plain text.

edited to replace all images with plain text. thanks
